# Creating a dev environment from existing website with nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, pug

So I've used Node.js in the past before, but I've never created a development environment from a pre-existing website. And now I have to. Plus, the previous developer worked in another state and used an iMac and developed in Coda. We were able to get all the files to my current workspace but I am trying to create the project in Visual Studio with Node Tools and am running into an issue. I fairly certain that its some kind of routing/config/setup issue but have not been able to suss it out and I've been rooting through package.json and config files for days.

All files are in the same relative directory from the root yet, and I've updated all packages and adjusted the code accordingly (I believe for the updated packages). However, when I try to start the site up, I run into this issue.

```
Debugger listening on [::]:5858
T:\IT\Website\ComfortCo(Dev)\ComfortCo(Dev)\views\index.jade:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { extends     global_layout
                                                          ^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token extends
at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
at Timeout.Module.runMain [as _onTimeout] (module.js:604:10)
at ontimeout (timers.js:365:14)
at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:237:5)
at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:207:5)
Press any key to continue...
```

The site uses jade with express and this is a pretty basic function of jade layouts. So I do not know why there is a Syntax Error.

Any ideas?

**Update**

So I was told that I did not have the most up-to-date versions of Node except I installed the most current version of Node when I installed Node Tools for VS and the pathing is correct.

However, when I ran `npm list` and `npm list -g` they came back with nothing even though my projects npm repository shows a whole list of packages installed and up-to-date. So I can only conclude that their is some pathing issue here. However, I have never configured Node paths. I've always just left them default. Any guidance here?

Comment: It seems like you are running a previous version of Node, one that doesn't support the `extend` keyword and the Classes feature. Could you check it?

Comment: I agree that it's probably a version issue but I'd like to point out that the error looks like it is not about the JS extends keyword, it's the jade template extends syntax.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with @Paul: when you run `node file.jade`, you get the exact same error (`extends` is Jade-syntax).

Answer (score 1):

The `extends` keyword is supported since Node version 4.x - see:

- http://node.green/#ES2015-functions-class-extends

It seems that you may be running an older version of Node but of course it's hard to tell because you provided no information about your runtime environment whatsoever.